# Accessing Google Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) Headers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, http-headers

My App Engine instance is currently secured behind Identity Aware Proxy (IAP). The App is a single page app and doesn't have a back end so no usage of python etc. Is it possible to still access the `X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email` header and then do stuff based on it?

I have tried this code to access the headers in the console but it isn't there:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Ideally I would have some code in one of my JS files along these lines:

```
if X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email == 'PersonA' then do this
else do this
```

Comment: If the user is authenticated then your client code (browser JavaScript) knows who the user is or can fetch that information via the OAuth Profile Scope. (Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email) Learn more here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email` is accessible only on server side. You can not access this header in client side.

Answer (score -1):

This information is available in your request header. So if you are using express you can extract it from the req object and store the content in a variable. Run your logic through that. ** Editing my answer to add some context **
so you could do this

```
var reqHeader = req.get('x-goog-authenticated-user-email'); 
// all ID's will have the prefix "acccounts.google.com:" -
```

so you will have to check if this is how you want to run your logic or you could edit the header to extract the email.